Get EHCache3 Statistics in Cache CREATED event handler
Tech stack: Spring 5, Ehcache3 (via JCache).
As part of upgrading ehcache from 2.10 to 3.10.8 wanted to know how exactly can I get cache statistics in cache event handler?

Wanted to know if given a cache, can I get statistics of it as getting a cache name(alias) is the event handler is unknown.
How can I get cache name (alias) inside the event handler

ehcache.xml
<cache-template name="defaultCacheTemplateWithListener">
<listeners>
    <listener>
        <class>com.mydomain.cache.MyDomainEhCache3CacheEventListener</class>
        <event-firing-mode>ASYNCHRONOUS</event-firing-mode>
        <event-ordering-mode>UNORDERED</event-ordering-mode>
        <events-to-fire-on>CREATED</events-to-fire-on>
    </listener>
</listeners>
</cache-template>

<!-- all caches defined below uses above template-->

class MyDomainEhCache3CacheEventListener
import org.ehcache.Cache;
import org.ehcache.event.CacheEvent;
import org.ehcache.event.CacheEventListener;
import org.ehcache.event.EventType;

public class MyDomainEhCache3CacheEventListener implements CacheEventListener<Object, Object> {


    @Override
    public void onEvent(CacheEvent<?, ?> cacheEvent) {
        EventType eventType = cacheEvent.getType();
        Cache<?, ?> cache = cacheEvent.getSource();
//Can I use this cache object to get the statistics instead of relying on its name?
        switch (eventType) {
            case CREATED:
                pollForStatistics(cache.toString());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }


private void pollForStatistics(String cacheName) {


        StatisticsService statisticsService = new DefaultStatisticsService();
        CacheStatistics statisticsGateway = statisticsService.getCacheStatistics(cacheName);
//Above line throwing exception as cache with given name doesnot exist

/*
Will read below from statisticsGateway
Cache Hits
Cache Misses
Cache Evictions
Cache Expired count
Cache Local Heap Size
Cache Hit Ratio
Cache Removal count
*/
}


